# Can I save layers as a template in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, layers, page-layout

Is there a way to set up layers without data & style sheets & color in a file and save as a template so that when I open a new document of that particular layout those layers are already there?

I know I can just take one and delete the data and save as a template and resave each time I create a file…I was just wondering if this can be saved as a page type under new docs?

Also, how do you edit and or delete a saved page preset?

Answer (score 1):

InDesign no longer ships with the handy templates it once had, but for your particular situation there are two resources.

1. The excellent [Tomaxxi Layers script](http://tomaxxi.com/2011/02/script-tomaxxilayers%C2%AE-add-layer-sets-to-document-updated/) by Marijan Tompa (tomaxxi) allows you to set up custom layer sets, including a default such as I use (3 layers -- "bg", "gfx" and "copy" -- that are my starting point in almost any project).
2. If you have specific templated starting points, with swatches, styles, etc., add the template files to a Collection in Bridge. If you keep them in one folder, you could even create a Smart Collection that automatically adds any InDesign document you put in that folder. This makes them immediately available no matter where you are in your directory structure in Bridge.

Collections and Smart Collections are two of the least-appreciated features of the Creative Suite's least appreciated tool. If you've not discovered Bridge yet, I invite you get into it and find how much time you can save.

To edit or delete document presets, choose `File > Document Presets > Define...`. The dialog lists all presets, including [Default]. Click on `Edit` to make changes, `Delete` to remove.

Comment: The tomaxxi link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also create "starting documents" for your own common sizes or project. (ahem, don't call 'em templates!)

If you create a document with layers, swatches, type styles, etc. you can save it as IDML and store it in a common place on your system or server. This way, you open it and the file has no filename or presumed directory location.

Yes, it's a workaround. I'd love if ID had more options to configure the defaults across *any* document. And specifically for Layers, it would be amazing to have "Paste Ignores Capitalization" to make "Paste Remembers Layers". I'd also love to see a way to map Layer 1 to another Layer I've named.

Comment: How exactly would this be different from a regular ("don't call them") template?

Comment: I think the built-in templates are only for page size, columns, etc., but not for any styles or layers. I'll have to check, but IDML files are also more portable, since you can share them with colleagues and friends rather than digging through the ID preferences and system subfolders.

Comment: Why "built-in"? A template is [just a normal document](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/files-templates.html#use_document_templates), with layers and styles and everything else. The only difference is that by default it opens As Copy. IDML is only a solution if you want to share with users of a lower version (and you'd need to take care not to use any features your colleagues don't have in their version).

Answer (score -2):

Dont forget about master pages. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please quote the relevant portion of the linked text in your answer. Link-only answers are not very valuable; we cannot rely on the longevity of external resources